# Is the following discrete variant of Miranda's theorem correct?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

The Intermediate Value Theorem says that, if $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, and $f(0)<0<f(1)$, then there is an $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

The following theorem can be seen as a discrete version of it. Suppose we partition the interval $[0,1]$ into any number of intervals. If $f(0)<0<f(1)$, then there is an interval $[x,y]\subset [0,1]$  on which $f$ switches signs, that is, $f(x)\leq 0\leq f(y)$. Note that this theorem holds even when $f$ is not continuous.

[Miranda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) is a multi-dimensional extension of the Intermediate Value Theorem. Let $f:[0,1]^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a continuous function such that $f_i(x)<0$ when $x_i=0$ and $f_i(x)>0$ when $x_i=1$, for all $i\in[d]$. Then there is a point $x\in[0,1]^d$ for which $f_i(x)=0$ for all $i\in[d]$.

I am looking for a discrete version of Miranda's theorem. Suppose we partition the box $[0,1]^d$ into a grid of arbitrary size, and suppose $f_i(x)<0$ when $x_i=0$ and $f_i(x)>0$ when $x_i=1$, for all $i\in[d]$. Does there exist a grid cell in which every function $f_i$ switch signs? That is: for all $i\in[d]$, there exists a corner in which $f_i\leq 0$ and a corner in which $f_i\geq 0$ (not necessarily the same corner for all $i$)?

Is there a similar theorem that can be seen as a discrete version of Miranda's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrete version of [Poincaré–Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem)
holds for each natural $n$ even when the function $f:[-1,1]^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is not continuous. Indeed, define a function $f^*:[-1,1]^n\to\mathbb R^n$ as follows. For any vertex $v$ of the grid put $f^*(v)=(\operatorname{sign} f_1(v),\dots, \operatorname{sign} f_n(v))$.
Now extend the function $f^*$ from the grid to a piecewise-linear function on $[-1,1]^n$ as follows.
Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in [-1,1]^n$ be any point. Pick any cell $C=\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]\ni x$ of the grid. For each natural $i\le n$ pick $\lambda_i\in [0,1]$ such that $x_i=\lambda_i a_i+ (1-\lambda_i)b_i$
Put $f^*(x)$ equal to $$\sum\left\{\prod_{i=1}^n |1-\varepsilon_i-\lambda_i|
f^*(\varepsilon_1 a_1+(1-\varepsilon_1) b_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n a_n+(1-\varepsilon_n) b_n)
 :(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n)\in\{0,1\}^n\right\}.$$
Since the function $f^*$ is continuous and satisfies the conditions of Poincaré–Miranda theorem,
there exists a point $x\in [-1,1]^n$ such that $f^*(x)=0$. Any cell of the grid containing the point $x$ is the required.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to strengthen the result and show that there is a single point $x$ (not a cell) such that, for every $i$, there is a point $x_i$ at distance $\delta$ from $x$ such that $f_i$ switches signs between $x$ and $x_i$?

Answer (score 0):

The discrete version you have stated is not true in general. Let's say you choose to divide $[0, 1]^2$ into a $2\times2$ grid with the $9$ lattice points/corners with the following signs of $(f_1, f_2)$. Note that the left of the grid corresponds to $x_1 = 0$ and the bottom of the grid corresponds to $x_2 = 0$.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
(-, +) & (-, +) & (+, +) \\
(-, +) & (+, -) & (+, -) \\
(-, -) & (+, -) & (+, -)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Choose the values at these corners however you want with the given signs and then extend the function linearly in each of the four subcells. In this example, it is not even possible to find a cell where you have at least one corner each of types $(-, -)$ and $(+,+)$. In general, it is quite difficult to control the signs of multiple functions simultaneously.

Comment: My question was probably not clear enough. What I meant is that, there exists a cell in which, for each function $f_i$ *separately*, there is a corner in which $f_i<0$ and a corner in which $f_i>0$ (it does not have to be the same corner for all $i$). In your example, all cells except the bottom-right one satisfy this condition.

Comment: Let's say we assign the values on the lattice points such that no such cell exited. Wouldn't the piecewise linear extension of this function be a counterexample to Miranda's theorem?